# Remove lines between the first and last occurrence of a marker line

Tags: awk

Using Linux tools like awk, how can I get all lines that are not between the `# NUMBERS` lines in the example below? In other words, I only want the line before the first `# NUMBERS` and after the last `# NUMBERS`.

Note: The marker is not always exactly `# NUMBERS`, but there may be any number of spaces between `#` and the `NUMBERS`

**Input**

```
 param1=23
 param2=34
 param3=4

 #    NUMBERS

 343546
 3454
 657
 534

 #   NUMBERS

 5454

 # NUMBERS

 param4=41
```

**Expected output**

```
 param1=23
 param2=34
 param3=4
 param4=41
```

Comment: Why shouldn't 5454 be printed?

Comment: I think the input format was recently modified.

Comment: my target to print only lines before the first "# NUMBERS"  and to print the lines after the last "# NUMBERS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `tac` and `awk`:

```
(
  cat data.txt | awk '/# *NUMBERS/ { nextfile } 1';
  tac data.txt | awk '/# *NUMBERS/ { nextfile } 1' | tac
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The main ideas are:

- Printing lines before "# NUMBER";
- Do not printing lines after "# NUMBER";
- At the end print buffer.

So

```
$> cat ./printOutsideNumbers.awk 
/#( )*NUMBER/ {
    if (insideSection == 0) {
        insideSection = 1;
    } else {
        sectionBuffer = ""
    }
}
! insideSection {
    print $0
}
insideSection && ! /#( )*NUMBER/ {
    sectionBuffer = sectionBuffer"\n"$0
}
END {
    print sectionBuffer
}
```

And

```
$> awk -f ./printOutsideNumbers.awk file.data.txt
param1=23
param2=34
param3=4



param4=41
```

Answer (score 0):

There is surely a more simpler code than this.

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /#[ ]*NUMBERS/){i++;next;}if(i%2==0 )print}' data.txt
```

Output

```
param1=23
param2=34
param3=4


param4=41
```

Comment: I'm not sure that OP is expecting that result.

Comment: its not print the "param4=41"

Answer (score 0):

Try next *awk* command. It divides file with string '# NUMBER' and prints first and last registers removing spaces.

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "#[[:space:]]+NUMBERS"; }
     FNR == 1 { sub(/^[[:space:]]*/, "", $0); sub(/[[:space:]]*$/, "", $0); print }
     END { sub(/^[[:space:]]*/, "", $0); sub(/[[:space:]]*$/, "", $0); print }' infile
```

Output:

```
param1=23
 param2=34
 param3=4
param4=41
```

Comment: your awk script print all the file!

Comment: My version of awk is: GNU Awk 4.0.0.  I'm not sure but perhaps older versions don't support '\s' as withespace. I've changed them to [:space:]. Output is the same in my system.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '1{h;d};H;${x;s/[^\n]*\(NUMBERS\).*\1.*\n//;p};d' file.data.txt
```

Explanation:

Slurp the file into `sed`'s hold space. Then at end of file, swap to HS, delete anything between `NUMBERS` and print out the remainder.

Or this:

```
sed '/NUMBERS/=;d' file.data.txt | 
sed -n '1h;${x;G;s/\n/,/;s,.*,sed &d file.data.txt,p}' | sh
```

Explanation:

Note line numbers of `NUMBERS`. Use the first and last addresses to build a `sed` script to delete the unwanted lines. Pass the script to the shell to run.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting "Greedy" line matching question.
"tac" one is dirty nice :) Mine is just like #3

```
BEGIN { buffer = ""; ignore = 0; }

/^# *NUMBERS/ {
    if (ignore == 0) {
        print buffer;
        ignore += 1;
    }

    buffer = ""; next;
} 

NF > 0 {
    buffer = sprintf("%s%s\n", buffer, $0)
}

END { print buffer; }
```

I think a FS="\n"; RS="" and then use greedy regex will also do the trick but that will be sedish, not awkish...